# Override the Content-Length property of HttpResponseMessage in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, httpresponse

I'm porting a legacy c++ based HTTP-server to C#. The server accommodates some legacy clients who want the Content-length to be **(actual Content-length) - 1**. We had to make this accommodation since the buggy clients were burned into firmware already :P

Anyways, C# doesnt let me override the **Content-length** property of **HttpResponseMessage** and throws a protocol-violation-exception.

Is there any parent class that I can use to make this modification?Any thoughts as to how I work around this?

Comment: What happens when you set `response.Content.Headers.ContentLength =something`? Is that where you get protocol-violation-exception?

Comment: I assume the exception occurs at 'later' stage, when another component tries to send such response.

Comment: That's right. The error happens when I actually write into the response stream. If I write more, I get an overrun exception and if I write less, I get an aborted exception saying not all bytes were received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explored all options and seems there is no straight-forward way to do intentional HTTP violation from ASP.NET HTTP handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement HTTP Server basing on [HttpServer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpserver(v=vs.118).aspx). An example how to do that can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use this approach since I have to enable this behavior on an IIS server code hosted on Microsoft Azure.

Comment: In this case I don't think it's possible. However, could you provide whole exception including whole callstack, please? Btw, Azure vm is not an option for you?

Comment: Also, as you are talking about firmware, do you have the http client source codes? May be it's possible to do some 'tricks' depending on how the code is written.